# Post a picture on Instagram using Graph API e.g. with python

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

For me, it seems that the API to interact with Instagram has changed completely in comparison to a year ago (probably due to the integration in facebook/meta). Basically, all approaches to access the Instagram API which I found on stackoverflow or github are not working anymore (e.g. instapy_cli).

I would like to create a Python3 script which uploads a picture to my Instagram CREATOR account. What I have:

- Created a Facebook/Meta developer app under https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- I can see a User Token and an App Token under https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken
- If I use the Meta Graph API Explorer under https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I can select the permission instagram_content_publish. After click "Generate Access Token" I can login, however, it is asked for an Instagram Business Account (see screenshot). I only have an Instagram CREATOR account.
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
- Several docs mentioned it Business and Creator accounts should work with Graph API (e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api)
- In Meta Accounts Center (https://accountscenter.instagram.com/profiles) I can see both my Facebook and my Instagram account.

Thanks for any hint!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzgqB.png